# How to calculate the reflection efficiency for an antenna?

Tags: electromagnetism, reflection, antennas

I want to calculate the reflection efficiency of a transmitting monopole antenna which is connected to a 50 ohm lossless transmission line. And I know that the input impedance of a monopole antenna is 36.5+21.25i ohm.

I tried the following ways to calculate the reflection efficiency but ended up with different values and I am not sure which one is correct:

(1 - ((36.5-50)/(36.5+50))^2) = 0.9756

(1 - ((36.5+21.25i-50)/(36.5+21.25i+50))^2) = 1.06359+0.048i

(1 - (absolute((36.5+21.25i-50)/(36.5+21.25i+50)))^2) = 0.92

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reflection efficiency is given by
$$1 - |\Gamma|^2 = 1 - \left|\frac{Z_L - Z_0}{Z_L + Z_0}\right|^2$$
where $\Gamma$ is the reflection coefficient, $Z_L$ is the load (antenna) impedance and $Z_0$ is the characteristic impedance of the transmission line. Your third expression gives the correct efficiency.